# Order dataframe/bar chart using a 2 coordinate data point - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data, that is summarized by a 2 coordinate data point (e.g. [0,2]). However my data frame, and therefore my bar chart are ordered alphabetically even though the coordinate is a factor data type.

The data frame/ggplot default behavior: [0,1], [0,13], [0,2]
What I want to happen: [0,1], [0,2], [0,13]

This coordinate variable was created by pasteing numbers from 2 columns

```
mutate(swimlane_coord = factor(paste0("[", sl_subsection_index, ",", sl_element_index, "]")))
```

where sl_subsection_index is an integer and sl_element_index is an integer.

There can be any combination of coordinates, so I would like to avoid having to manually force the factor definitions.

Here is an example of the data:

```
structure(list(application_type1 = c("SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", 
"SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", 
"SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", "SamsungTV", 
"SamsungTV", "SamsungTV"), variant_uuid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", 
"BackNav"), class = "factor"), allStreamSec = c("curatedCatalog", 
"curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", 
"curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", 
"curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", "curatedCatalog", 
"curatedCatalog"), swimlane_coord = structure(c(1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 25L, 29L), .Label = c("[0,0]", 
"[0,1]", "[0,10]", "[0,11]", "[0,12]", "[0,13]", "[0,14]", "[0,2]", 
"[0,3]", "[0,4]", "[0,5]", "[0,6]", "[0,7]", "[0,8]", "[0,9]", 
"[1,0]", "[1,1]", "[1,3]", "[1,4]", "[1,5]", "[1,7]", "[2,0]", 
"[2,11]", "[3,1]", "[3,11]", "[3,2]", "[3,5]", "[3,6]", "[3,7]", 
"[3,8]"), class = "factor"), ESPerVisitBySL = c(1.775, 1.83333333333333, 
0.976190476190476, 0.966666666666667, 1.08333333333333, 1, 1.33333333333333, 
1.45161290322581, 1.68965517241379, 1.44827586206897, 1.5, 1, 
1, 1), UESPerVisitBySL = c(13, 16.4, 8.80952380952381, 8.4, 9.33333333333333, 
1, 11.5555555555556, 17.741935483871, 16.3448275862069, 8.10344827586207, 
15.3571428571429, 6, 7, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    application_type1 = c("SamsungTV", "SamsungTV"), variant_uuid = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Control", 
    "BackNav"), class = "factor"), allStreamSec = c("curatedCatalog", 
    "curatedCatalog"), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 7:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Notice that [3,11] comes before [3,2].

The only packages I have loaded are tidyverse and data.table.

Thank you
Harry

Comment: Hi Harry. To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**, the **code** you tried and the **packages** you used? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you could

1. arrange your data.frame by `sl_subsection_index` and `sl_element_index`
2. after doing so you could set the order of `swimlane_coord` using `forcats::fct_inorder`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

d %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    sl_subsection_index = gsub("^\\[(\\d+),\\d+\\]$", "\\1", swimlane_coord),
    sl_element_index = gsub("^\\[\\d+,(\\d+)\\]$", "\\1", swimlane_coord)
  ) %>%
  arrange(as.integer(sl_subsection_index), as.integer(sl_element_index)) %>%
  mutate(swimlane_coord = forcats::fct_inorder(factor(swimlane_coord))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(swimlane_coord)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>